# How to build a proper namespace in Scala?

Tags: scala, enums, namespaces, inner-classes, case-class

I'm new to Scala and right now I'm creating my first enumeration (with case classes to override `toString`).

```
package views.helper.button

abstract sealed class Size(identifier: Option[String])
{
    def this(identifier: String) = this( Some( identifier ) )

    override def toString: String = identifier match
    {
        case Some( identifier ) => "btn-" + identifier
        case _ => ""
    }

    case object Mini extends Size( "mini" )
    case object Small extends Size( "small" )
    case object Default extends Size( None )
    case object Large extends Size( "normal" )
}
```

Coming from a Java background this was my first attempt. Accessing the case objects like `button.Size.Mini` seems very natural to me. But it looks like I'm unable to access the class' inner case objects. Placing them below the `Size` class works fine but results in a confusing namespace.

Why is that? How would you model this behavior? Can this be done more elegant by an object extending `Enumeration` (I figured `toString` would become an issue..)?

Comment: I have seen `object` being used for namespacing. You realize that `object` is a class with its singleton instance created, rt?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use case class, you need to put the case object in the companion object of Size (equivalent to static visibility)

```
package views.helper.button

abstract sealed class Size(identifier: Option[String])
{
    def this(identifier: String) = this( Some( identifier ) )

    override def toString: String = identifier match
    {
        case Some( identifier ) => "btn-" + identifier
        case _ => ""
    }
}

object Size {
    case object Mini extends Size( "mini" )
    case object Small extends Size( "small" )
    case object Default extends Size( None )
    case object Large extends Size( "normal" )
}
```